# output raw javascript using handlebars

Tags: handlebars.js, highlight.js

I created a mini CMS to store code snippets. 
It pulls articles form a mongodb database.
I use highlgiht.js to display the code and allow users to copy the snippets.

With HTML, everything works as expected:

```
{{#article}}
    <h1>Demo</h1>
    {{{markup}}} <!-- prints raw HTML in the screen, yay! -->

    <h1>HTML</h1>
    <pre class="pre-scrollable"><code class="html">{{markup}}</code></pre>
    <!-- prints escaped HTML in the screen, and highlight.js highlights it perfectly! YAY -->

{{/article}}
```

Now, with Javascript:

```
{{#article}}

    <h1>Demo</h1>
    {{{js}}} <!-- prints empty script tag: <script></script> -->

    <h1>JS</h1>
    <pre class="pre-scrollable"><code class="html">{{js}}</code></pre>
    <!-- prints <script></script> -->

{{/article}}
```

The content of the field "js" in the database is "console.log("test");"

Why is it not outputting what's saved in the db, but instead it is making up a new script tag on its own??

Thank you!

Comment: Handlebars won't change `console.log` with script, so either `js` value is actually `<script></script>` or something else is changing that value. Show how are you compiling handlebars and put a `console.log` when passing the context to handlebars, and show us the output.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande: When i do a console.log from my article controller, I get the raw javascript as the actual content of the document field.

Here's what else I found out:
- it's not the browser, it happens in all of them;
- it's not highlight.js as this works as expected:
```<pre class="pre-scrollable"><code class="javascript">$(document).ready(function() {$('pre code').each(function(i, e) {hljs.highlightBlock(e)});});</code></pre>```
It's something with handlebars.

Comment: Also, I am using this handlebars wrapper in my app: https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars

Answer (score 0):

After pulling most of my hair, I figured it out:

I had a name collision where my document property/field was named "js" and that conflicted with the name of a helper from a library I am using:
https://github.com/helpers/handlebars-helpers/blob/master/lib/html.js#L85